# Java loading an external class in runtime

Tags: java, class, url, methods, jar

I have yet another issue which the answer is eluding me.  I wish to take a class from an external jar at runtime and grab a method from it and pass it a parameter.  My code below currently opens the jar and grabs the class and runs the method but when I try and pass it a parameter, the method runs but I get an InvocationTargetException.  Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
    String path = "test.jar";
    URL[] classes = {new File(path).toURI().toURL()};
    URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (classes, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    try {
        Class classToLoad = Class.forName("testClass", true, child);
        Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("testMethod", String.class);
        Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
        Object result = method.invoke(instance, new String("Test from method!"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is the error it throws:

```
Test from method!
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Load.loadJar(LoadTerrem.java:33)
    at Load.<init>(LoadTerrem.java:18)
    at Load.main(LoadTerrem.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MenuSingleplayer.LoadWorlds(MenuSingleplayer.java:210)
    at MenuSingleplayer.setup(MenuSingleplayer.java:89)
    at M0.LoadGame(M0.java:76)
    ... 7 more
```

As you can see, the method executes, printing out the string passed to it but then throws an error on the line:

```
Object result = method.invoke(instance, new String("Test from LoadTerrem!"));
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`InvocationTargetException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) is thrown when the invoked method (`testMethod` in your case) throws an exception. From the docs:

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

Judging from your stack trace (the "caused by"-part to be precise) it looks like `testMethod` causes `MenuSingleplayer.LoadWorlds` to be called, which raises a `NullPointerException`. This `NullPointerException` propagates up until it reaches the reflective call, at which point the it is wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the MenuSingleplayer.LoadWorlds method. It says a NPE happened there. There is nothing to do with reflection. It's OK:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at MenuSingleplayer.LoadWorlds(MenuSingleplayer.java:210)
```

Comment: Well, I feel a little... stupid now. Thanks though you solved it!